# Convergence of a series defined with factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is the series in question.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \quad \text{where} \quad a_n = \frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!(n+1)!}$$
Naturally, I tried the Ratio test, but it turned out $L = 1$ so the test was inconclusive. In such series, if the Ratio test doesn't work, what can I try?

Comment: Use Stirling's Formula.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for a good idea, but I tried Stirling's Formula with the Root test and again got inconclusive result.

Comment: Your question is unclear what you are showing is a sequence and not a series.

Comment: @WiWo Sorry about that, I fixed it.

Comment: What about using binomial theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this theorem

> Let $\{a_n\} $ and $\{b_n\}$ be two sequences with $a_n>0$ and $b_n>0 $ for all $n \geq N$ and let $c_n = b_n - b_{n+1} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ then if there is a positive constant $r$ such that $c_n \geq r > 0$ for all $n \geq N $ then $\sum a_n$ converges

with your series (simplifying you obtain $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{2n+1}{2(n+2)} $) and $b_{n+1} = n+2$ so $$c_n = n+1-(n+2)\frac{2n+1}{2(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

therefore, we can use $r = \frac12$ to show that $\sum a_n $ converges.

Comment: What's the name of this method?

Comment: mmh don't know it is a general result in Apostol Calculus, but it is very similar to Raabe's test

Comment: it is exercise 15 of section 10.16 if you're interested :) ( there is also the divergence criteria stated there!)

Comment: This method is quite interesting thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

By the duplication formula for Gamma function you have

$$
\left( {2\,n} \right)! = {{4^{\,n} } \over {\sqrt \pi  }}\left( {n - 1/2} \right)!n!
$$